# Cannot navigate to different screen using FCM onMessage

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am trying to navigate to a different screen using [Get](https://pub.dev/packages/get) when a user taps on the notification triggered from the onMessage function while the app is on foreground. So far I have not been able to do that.

Here's what I have done so far:

```
  void initState(){ 
    super.initState();
    var initializationSettingsAndroid  = AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/splash');
    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(android:initializationSettingsAndroid);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
    
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification android = message.notification?.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            notification.hashCode,
            notification.title,
            notification.body,
            NotificationDetails(
              android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                channel.id,
                channel.name,
                channel.description,
                icon: '@drawable/splash',
                playSound: true
              ),
            ));
            Get.to(OrdersScreen());
      }
    });
  }
```

I get the notification but when I tap, nothing happens. I also get the following exception in the logs.

> E/flutter (17567): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)]
> Unhandled Exception: You are trying to use contextless navigation
> without E/flutter (17567):       a GetMaterialApp or Get.key.
> E/flutter (17567):       If you are testing your app, you can use:
> E/flutter (17567):       [Get.testMode = true], or if you are running
> your app on E/flutter (17567):       a physical device or emulator,
> you must exchange your [MaterialApp] E/flutter (17567):       for a
> [GetMaterialApp]. E/flutter (17567): E/flutter (17567): #0
> GetNavigation.global package:get/…/src/extension_navigation.dart:1052
> E/flutter (17567): #1      GetNavigation.to
> package:get/…/src/extension_navigation.dart:511 E/flutter (17567): #2
> _MyAppState.initState. package:flutter_complete_guide/main.dart:146 E/flutter (17567): #3
> _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47) E/flutter (17567): #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19) E/flutter (17567): #5      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1170:7) E/flutter (17567): #6      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData
> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11) E/flutter (17567): #7
> _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591:14) E/flutter (17567): #8      _StreamImplEvents.handleNext
> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:706:11) E/flutter (17567): #9
> _PendingEvents.schedule. (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:663:7) E/flutter (17567): #10
> _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1346:47) E/flutter (17567): #11     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1258:19) E/flutter (17567): #12     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1162:7) E/flutter (17567): #13     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.
> (dart:async/zone.dart:1202:23) E/flutter (17567): #14     _rootRun
> (dart:async/zone.dart:1354:13) E/flutter (17567): #15
> _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1258:19) E/flutter (17567): #16     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1162:7) E/flutter (17567): #17     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.
> (dart:async/zone.dart:1202:23) E/flutter (17567): #18
> _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21) E/flutter (17567): #19     _startMicrotaskLoop
> (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5) E/flutter (17567):
> D/ViewRootImpl@874c66fMainActivity: stopped(false) old=false

Comment: My understanding is that onMessageOpenedApp is fired when the app is in the background state.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this using the navigatorkey.

Created the global key:

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: "Main Navigator");
```

Initialized it in the MaterialApp:

```
MaterialApp( 
        navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
```

The used it inside onMessage function:

```
navigatorKey.currentState.push(
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => OrdersScreen()));
```

Answer (score 0):

to open a notification you have to use this

```
 FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
        // print('A new onMessageOpenedApp event was published!');

         Get.to(OrdersScreen());
      });
```